# Is there a way to hide the header when result filter is empty?

Tags: angular, angular8

- I want to get functionality like if the filter result1 is zero then it should not show the header.
- In the code you can see that there is a global array which  has many categories. When searching  when the result filter is zero, i don't want to show the header name . If it doesn't match any category then i have to show no result.
- We are filtering the category out from the global array which has material for all the categories ,then  showing that category content.
- When i am using hidden=[searchText] in h1 , then it is working fine but then the header is not coming.

Basically I want to hide the header when there is no result.

**app.html**

**This is the place where the filter is used for the global array and it shows the questions and the answers.**

```
<div class="faq-section text-center">

**Using ngContainer to check if the result is empty or not**
<ng-container *ngIf="( globalList | filter : searchText) as result1">

    *This is the heading that i want to hide when there is no content but it the header is showing when the contents
    are searched in the search bar*

    <h1 *ngIf="!result1.length<=0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-out-back" data-aos-duration="1200"
        data-aos-once="true">
       
        <!---->  </h1>
    *PLace to show the contents*

    <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-out-back" data-aos-duration="1200" data-aos-once="true"

         class="row justify-content-center no-gutters">

        <div class="col-11 faq-list" style="text-align: left;">

            <mat-accordion displayMode="flat"
                           [multi]="false"
                           #accordion="matAccordion">

                <!--*ngFor="let faq of faqList | filter : searchText" -->
                <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let faq of faqList | filter : searchText" [expanded]="faq.isExpanded"
                                     (opened)="beforePanelOpened(faq,'faqList')"
                                     (closed)="beforePanelClosed(faq)"
                                     (afterCollapse)="afterPanelClosed($event)"
                                     (afterExpand)="afterPanelOpened($event)"
                                     style="font-size:0.9em;font-weight: 500;color: #2c333f;"
                                     #mapanel="matExpansionPanel" [hideToggle]="true">

                    **This is a mat expansion for showing the questions and the answers which will come from the
                    filter**
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-11 no-padding" ng-class=" {'open': faq.open}"
                                 [ngClass]="{'open':faq.isExpanded === true}"> {{faq.question}}
                            </div>

                            <!-- {{faq.question}} -->
                        </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description class="plusicon">
                            <mat-icon *ngIf="!faq.isExpanded">
                               
                            </mat-icon>
                            <mat-icon *ngIf="faq.isExpanded">
                               
                            </mat-icon>
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                    <span style="white-space: pre-line;">{{faq.answer}}
                              </span>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
                <li style="list-style: none;" *ngIf="result1.length == 0">
                    >This region will come when no result will come
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <span class="justify-content-center">No result</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>


            </mat-accordion>

        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

This condition is syntactically wrong

```
*ngIf="!result1.length<=0"
```

What you're asking is to check if the negation of `boolean` value of `result1.length` is minor or equal to a number.
This is an impossible comparison.
What you actually want is the negation of the comparison between two numbers:  `result1.length` and `0`.
The right notation then would be

```
*ngIf="!(result1.length<=0)"
```

That's in the end just a clumsy way to check

```
*ngIf="result1.length>0"
```